# Elastic search how to handle apostrophe with and without

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am having data in elastic search which is stored as

```
field1:DAVID'S RD
field1:DAVID's PARK
field1:DAVID'S JUNCTION
field1:DAVID'S REST
   .......
..............
```

Case1:
If the input is `DAVID’S`(Where the apostrophe character is different). It is not returning result in correct order some records are missing in result.

Case2:
If the input is `DAVID'S` it is giving correct result.

Case3:
If the input is `DAVIDS`. Again it is giving same response as case1.

So, how to handle in elastic search for handling all three cases.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation here is to use the [english analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) for your field1 that will normalize all variations of the root "david".

The standard analyzer will consider this 3 variations as they are.

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "text": ["DAVID'S", "DAVID’S", "DAVIDS"],
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "david's",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "david’s",
      "start_offset" : 8,
      "end_offset" : 15,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "davids",
      "start_offset" : 16,
      "end_offset" : 22,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

But english analyzer will understand the root of the three.

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "text": ["DAVID'S", "DAVID’S", "DAVIDS"],
  "analyzer": "english"
}
```

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "david",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "david",
      "start_offset" : 8,
      "end_offset" : 15,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "david",
      "start_offset" : 16,
      "end_offset" : 22,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

To set this analyzer you can create an index with this settings.

```
PUT test_rahul
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "english"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Test document**

```
POST test_rahul/_doc
{
  "field1": "DAVID'S RD"
}
```

**Query**

```
POST test_rahul/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field1": "davids"
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_rahul",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "TNCY_ncB46EpgstaBC3E",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : "DAVID'S RD"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you only want to filter out the apostrophes then you can use the [Apostrophe Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-apostrophe-tokenfilter.html), but english analizer works good in general.

Comment: is there any difference between standard and english, will it affect existing search response in which I am not using any analyzer which means default stndard analyzer?

Comment: The standard analyzer only changes to lowercase and tokenize based in spaces basically. English analyzer does another stuff like stemming words to its root (to match things like conjugations and plurals) In my answer you can see I used the analyze API, you can use to make tests on how your data will be indexed.

Comment: It does not work for "don't" so it's not perfect.